# PongGame - шар пролетает сквозь ракетки

Tags: c#, .net, разработка-игр, консоль

Проблема описана в заголовке. Я написал следующую функцию для обработки столкновения шарика с ракеткой (в классе Ball.cs):

```
public bool IsCollideWithPaddle()
        {
            if (X == pad1.X + 1)
            {
                return (Y >= pad1.Y - pad1.Length / 2) && (Y <= pad1.Y + pad1.Length / 2);
            }
            else if (X == pad2.X - 1)
            {
                return (Y >= pad2.Y - pad2.Length / 2) && (Y <= pad2.Y + pad2.Length / 2);
            }
            else return false;
        }
```

Но не было бы вопроса, будь она рабочей. Шарик просто пролетает сквозь ракетку. Причём, если возвращать true, если по координате X шарик совпадает с ракеткой, то отражение от всей этой вертикальной плоскости будет работать. То есть проблема заключается именно в логике этой функции, но я не могу понять где я ошибся.
Вот все файлы игры:

Ball.cs

```
namespace Ping_Pong
{
    class Ball
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int SpeedX { get; set; }
        public int SpeedY { get; set; }
        public int BotBorder { get; set; }
        public int RightBorder { get; set; }
        public Paddle pad1 { get; set; }
        public Paddle pad2 { get; set; }

        public Ball(int width, int height, Paddle p1, Paddle p2)
        {
            X = width / 2;
            Y = height / 2;
            SpeedX = -1;
            SpeedY = -1;
            BotBorder = height;
            RightBorder = width;
            pad1 = p1;
            pad2 = p2;
        }
        public void Erase()
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(X - SpeedX, Y - SpeedY);
            Console.Write(" ");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
        }
        public void Draw()
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
            Console.Write(" ");
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Erase();
        }
        public void Move()
        {
            if (IsCollideWithBorder()) { SpeedY = -SpeedY; }
            if (IsCollideWithPaddle()) { SpeedX = -SpeedX; }
            X += SpeedX;
            Y += SpeedY;
            Draw();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        public bool IsCollideWithBorder()
        { if (Y <= 0 || Y >= BotBorder) return true; else return false; }
        public bool IsCollideWithPaddle()
        {
            if (X == pad1.X + 1)
            {
                return (Y >= pad1.Y - pad1.Length / 2) && (Y <= pad1.Y + pad1.Length / 2);
            }
            else if (X == pad2.X - 1)
            {
                return (Y >= pad2.Y - pad2.Length / 2) && (Y <= pad2.Y + pad2.Length / 2);
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Board.cs

```
    class Board
    {
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public Board(int h = 20, int w = 60)
        { Height = h; Width = w; }
        public void CreateWindow()
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.WindowHeight = Height + 1;
            Console.WindowWidth = Width + 1;

            Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
            Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Paddle.cs

```
namespace Ping_Pong
{
    class Paddle
    {
        int boardHeight;
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }

        public Paddle(int x, int Height) // x - position, Height - b1.Height
        {
            this.boardHeight = Height;
            X = x;
            Y = Height / 2 + 6;
            Length = 5;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern ushort GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
        public bool IsKeyPushed(ConsoleKey vKey)
        { return 0 != (GetAsyncKeyState((int)vKey) & 0x8000); }

        public void Draw()
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            for (int i = Y - (Length / 2); i <= (Y + Length / 2); i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y + i);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y + Length);
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        }
        public void Erase()
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            for (int i = Y - (Length / 2); i <= (Y + Length / 2); i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y + i);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y + Length);
        }
        public void Move(ConsoleKey Up, ConsoleKey Down)
        {
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (IsKeyPushed(Up))
            { 
                if (Y >= 2)
                {
                    Erase();
                    Y--;
                    Draw();
                } 
            }
            if (IsKeyPushed(Down))
            { 
                if (Y <= boardHeight * 2 + 3)
                {
                    Erase();
                    Y++;
                    Draw();
                } 
            }
            if (IsKeyPushed(ConsoleKey.Escape))
            { Environment.Exit(0); }
        }
    }
}
```

Game.cs

```
namespace Ping_Pong
{
    class Game
    {
        private const int BoardHeight = 30;
        private const int BoardLength = 100;
        public Board b;
        public Paddle p1;
        public Paddle p2;
        public Ball ball;
        public int countLeft;
        public int countRight;
        public Game()
        {
            b = new Board(BoardHeight, BoardLength);
            p1 = new Paddle(2, 5);
            p2 = new Paddle(BoardLength - 2, 5);
            ball = new Ball(BoardLength, BoardHeight, p1, p2);
            countLeft = 0;
            countRight = 0;
        }
        // метод для обновления карты (потом пригодится)
        public void Init()
        {
            b = new Board(BoardHeight, BoardLength);
            p1 = new Paddle(2, 5);
            p2 = new Paddle(BoardLength - 2, 5);
            ball = new Ball(BoardLength, BoardHeight, p1, p2);
        }
        public void Run()
        {
            b.CreateWindow();
            p1.Draw();
            p2.Draw();
            ball.Draw();
            while (true)
            {
                ball.Move();
                p1.Move(ConsoleKey.W, ConsoleKey.S);
                p2.Move(ConsoleKey.UpArrow, ConsoleKey.DownArrow);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
namespace Ping_Pong
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game game = new Game();
            game.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка по всей видимости кроется в методе Draw(), либо Move() класса Ball, но я не могу понять в чём именно там ошибка.

Comment: `Move` - меняет значения полей, но изменение значения поля, не вызывает метод `Draw`, который нарисует новое положение. По сути, рисуется только первое положение и все.

Comment: Боже, спасибо, я видимо случайно удалил эту строку

Comment: Но теперь возник ещё один баг, шарик игнорирует левую ракетку, но от правой отскакивает. Раньше такого не было, тем более код обработки этого случая написан для обеих ракеток одинаково. Не могу понять в чём проблема

Comment: Актуализируйте вопрос и код в вопросе.

Comment: Конечно, сейчас